# Get uncertain value with ThreadLocal.get()

Tags: java, thread-local

I'm doing some transformation of org.w3c.dom.Document with org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.
Here is the code:

```
    protected Document transform(Document document, OlapWidget olapWidget, String name, String description) throws TransformerException, IOException {
        Transformer transformer = XmlUtils.getTransformer(getSession(), xslUri, true);
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        transformer.setParameter("reportTitle", StringUtils.coalesce(name, ""));
        transformer.setParameter("reportDescription", StringUtils.coalesce(description, ""));
        transformer.setParameter("hideSpans", isHideSpans() ? "yes" : "no");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), domResult);
        return (Document) domResult.getNode();
    }
```

As I understand it transforms some document using template. In this case this template is String xslUri.
This template is just a .xsl file. This file uses one of my classes:

```
<lxslt:component prefix="XsltHelper"
    functions="hideTotals">
    <lxslt:script lang="javaclass" src="com.texunatech.nss.util.xsl.XsltUtils"/>
</lxslt:component>
```

Code of this class

```
public class XsltUtils {
    public static String hideTotals() {
        OlapWidget report = OlapReportHolder.getReport();
        if (report == null) {
            return "no";
        } else {
            return Arrays.asList(OlapConstants.PROVIDER_AGGREGATED_ALL_DATASET, OlapConstants.PROVIDER_ALL_DATASET, OlapConstants.PROVIDER_DATASET,
                    OlapConstants.PROVIDER_AGGREGATED_ALL_DATASET_HIST, OlapConstants.PROVIDER_ALL_DATASET_HIST, OlapConstants.PROVIDER_DATASET_HIST).contains(report.getDataSlice().getDataCubeCode()) ? "yes" : "no";
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem is in `OlapReportHolder.getReport()`. Sometimes I get some object with this method. But more often I have null using this method, which is incorrect. It looks like absolutely random.

The code is in OlapReportHolder is:

```
public class OlapReportHolder implements Serializable {
    
    private static final ThreadLocal<OlapWidget> reportHolder = new ThreadLocal<OlapWidget>();

    public static void setReport(OlapWidget report) {
        reportHolder.set(report);
    }


    public static OlapWidget getReport() {
        return reportHolder.get();
    }
}
```

As you can see it uses ThreadLocal. What is the problem with this code? Why is result unstable? I should always get an object with this method, but I don't. How it works? How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If `setReport` is called in one thread and `getReport` in another thread, then obviously you will not get what you set before.